# Laravel many to many and hasMany, N+1

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I got a model Event that has many private classes

```
  public function privateclasses()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Privateclass::class);
  }
```

This is working perfect

---

Model Privateclass and User is connected in table "privateclass_user" with foreign key "privateclass_id" and "user_id".

In model Privateclass.php:

```
public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }
```

This is also working, but when I get the event the query count is high.
How do I Eager Load this?

```
$event = Event::with('users')->get(); <-- NOT WORKING
```

In short: I want all users connected to privateclass that belongs to an Event.

Comment: `belongsTo` means Your `Event` has `user_id` and `Many` part means it must return array.  Make it `hasMany` - means that it has items that have `event_id`.

Comment: Should your query not be: `$event = Event::with('privateclasses.users')->get();`?

Comment: I think You've to use this post: https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

> To eager load a relationship's relationships, you may use "dot" syntax.

Looks like you need:

```
Event::with('privateclasses.users')
```

or:

```
Event::with([
    'privateclasses' => [
        'users'
    ]
])
```